# Determine the smallest number such that the division by $12,20,38$ left the same remainder $10$.

Tags: number-theory

I was studying gcd and I found this problem. No idea how to solve:
Determine the smallest number such that the division by $12,20,38$ leaves the same remainder $10$.

Comment: I think 10 is the smallest positive number with this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the smallest number **greater than ten**. Say it is $n$: then $n-10$ is a multiple of $12,20,38$, hence it is a multiple of $\text{lcm}(12,20,38)=1140.$ it follows that the solution is $\color{red}{1150}$.